# How to enable Multipart/resume Download in IIS?

Tags: iis

I have a 2 Gb File on IIS server.

How do I enable multipart download to this file ?

**For eg:** An app called as Download Accelator Pus (DAP) works by splitting the download file into different parts & fetches each part in parallel.
It also allows resuming downloads if for some reason download is interrupted.

What settings do I need to configure on my server to achieve this ?